# How to exclude #VALUE Errors which return me otherwise in a IFERROR formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

=IFERROR(INDEX('[xx.xlsx]xx'!$C:$C,SMALL(IF(('[xx.xlsx]xx'!$F:$F="PENDING PAYMENT")*('[xx.xlsx]xx'!$AK:$AK=""),ROW('[xx.xlsx]xx'!$C:$C)),ROW(1:1)),1),"")

I'm trying to extract data from another dataset based on the above IFERROR, IF formula. However due to a few #Value Error in column AK of the raw datasheet, I'm unable to return the values of the other data which meets the condition. Is there a way to exclude the #value errors in the formula ? or place another IFERROR within the formula ?

I have tried removing the #value errors in the raw datasheet manually but that is just not feasible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were after?

[image: No, I don't think I will]

Formula used:

> =IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C;SMALL(IF(IFERROR(($F:$F="PENDING PAYMENT")*($AK:$AK="");FALSE);ROW($C:$C));ROW(1:1));1);"")

Obviously not using a different workbook just for visually presenting it to you :)

Comment: Looks like what I'm after ! Could you explain your rationale and way of doing it ?

Comment: With the IF, you were going after a ´TRUE´ value so I gave it a `FALSE` if it errors out and then it doesn't do anything (your false-condition isn't set).

Comment: Got it thanks ! Also to check if it is possible to condition an if for column (which is a date) greater or lesser than a certain date or TODAY ?

Comment: Dates can be compared that way (since dates are actually just values presented in a certain way for us to read it easily) but you might have to fiddle around a bit in case your pc/local's format for dates is different from the standard that excel expects, i.e. 1/3/2023 being either 1st of March or 3rd of January.